# Scrolling to the child element of a scrollable parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scrollable `ul`, and several `li`-items. My goal is to scroll to the `li`-item with certain id when the user presses a button.

I have a code which seems to work, but there are two issues

1. If I scroll down to the end of the list as page loads, the button does not work anymore. Comment out and uncomment the line as mentioned in the code to see what I mean
2. If I am already on the wanted item in the list, I want to stay on the same place if I press the scroll-button.

I guess, both issues are because of some relative coordinates, but I can't figure out how this system works. Help me please!

HTML:

```
<ul id="container">
  <li id="1">stuff1</li>
  <li id="2">stuff2</li>
  <li id="3">stuff3</li>
  <li id="4">stuff4</li>
  <li id="5">stuff5</li>
  <li id="6">stuff6</li>
  <li id="7">stuff7</li>
  <li id="8">stuff8</li>
  <li id="9">stuff9</li>
  <li id="10">stuff10</li>
  <li id="11">stuff11</li>
  <li id="12">stuff12</li>
  <li id="13">stuff13</li>
  <li id="14">stuff14</li>
  <li id="15">stuff15</li>
  <li id="16">stuff16</li>
</ul>
<button id = 'btn'>Scroll to element with id = 9</button>
```

JS:

```
var $container = $('#container')[0];

// $container.scrollTop = $container.scrollHeight;
// If I uncomment the above line, the code does not work any more
$('#btn').click(function(){
     $container.scrollTop =  $('#9').position().top;
});
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
}

ul li {
  margin: 30px;
  border: solid;
}
```

See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rck1ow93/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 9 element will be positioned relative to the scroll too. You have to append the current scroll to the 9 position, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rck1ow93/2/

```
$container.scrollTop = $container.scrollTop+$('#9').position().top;
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to Jorge's answer, in addition to taking scroll into account, you might want to use .offset() instead of .position(), as it will give you the correct position.  So change

```
$container.scrollTop =  $('#9').position().top;
```

to

```
$container.scrollTop += $('#9').offset().top;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t06fjtqd/

Answer (score 0):

why not use [scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

```js
$('#9').scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "start"})
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-cgkd8z?file=index.html